# Python importing module is choosing previous directory

Tags: python

Having a strange error here. I had a previous directory structured as follows

```
main.py
foldername
     modulename.py
```

now in main.py I called modulename.py by using `import modulename.py as mn`

now I am making changes but I still want to use the modules as before, so in a completely different location on my computer I have set up the structure as before:

```
newmain.py
foldername
     modulename.py
```

to make sure I am working in the right directory I used:

```
import os
os.chdir('NewMainPath/')
```

which correctly sets the directory of the file but if I now use

```
import modulename.py as mn
```

it for some reason is linking to the previous modulename.py
That means if I make any changes it won't pick them up and is just linking to the previous location and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `os.chdir(newpath)`

Try using

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/newpath')

import file
```

Also worth reading: [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)